# How many telephone numbers have no $0$ in the prefix (first three numbers)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I got that the total number of telephone numbers: $10^{10}$, but should I do the number of one $0$ in prefix, number of two $0$ in prefix and number of three $0$ in prefix, and subtract them. But I don't know how to count the number of $0$ in the prefix.

Comment: In the US, at least, 0 and 1 are not valid numbers for the first digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all numbers have $10$ digits, $3$ in the prefix and $7$ in the remainder, and your only limitation is that you can not have a $0$ in the prefix, you should have:
$$9^3\cdot 10^7$$

Possibilities. If say, you could not have either of two digits in the prefix (i.e. a choice of $8$ digits, you would simply replace the $9$ by an $8$.

Comment: does it mean that if I change 0 in the problem to any other numbers, the answer will be the same?

Comment: @SSS - yes it does.